# Wordpress: disable links for get_the_category_list function?

Tags: php, wordpress

Hey my theme uses this function to display the categories a post has, but it also creates links which I would like to get rid of. I prefer php rather than a javascript solution.

Here is the code:

```
<p class="postmeta">
    <?php if ( 'post' == get_post_type() ) : // Hide category and tag text for pages on Search ?>
        <?php
            /* translators: used between list items, there is a space after the comma */
            $categories_list = get_the_category_list( __( ', ', 'gridster' ) );
            if ( $categories_list && gridster_categorized_blog() ) :
        ?>
            <?php /*printf( __( '%1$s', 'gridster' ), $categories_list );*/ echo $categories_list; ?>
        <?php endif; // End if categories ?>


    <?php endif; // End if 'post' == get_post_type() ?>
</p>
```

[Link to the codex reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_category_list)

How can I void those links?

or get rid of links all together from DOM (but this might create more work as the actual text is between the `<a>` tags

**HTML**

```
 <p class="postmeta"> 
    <a target="_blank" href="http://whatever.com/category/default/" title="View all posts in Default" rel="category tag">Default</a>
</p>
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 13):

If you just want a text-string returned and use the native `get_the_categories()` function, you could simply wrap it in [PHP's `strip_tags()` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) to remove all HTML that is returned:

```
echo strip_tags( get_the_category_list(__( ', ', 'gridster' ));
```

Comment: Simplified version for others to copy/paste: `echo strip_tags(get_the_category_list(', '));`

Comment: @john_911 Please approve this one as the correct answer

Answer (score 3):

You can try modifying this to fit your needs:

```
<?php
foreach((get_the_category()) as $category) {
    echo $category->cat_name . ' ';
}
?>
```

(From http://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/how-to-get-a-wordpress-category-name-without-the-link/ )

Comment: I have modified this to the following:
`
<?php
$categoryList = '';
foreach (get_the_category() as $category) {
    $categoryList .= $category->cat_name . ' ';
}
echo str_replace(' ', ',', trim($categoryList));
`

This can be encapsulated within a function and reused as needed.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to [copy the original function](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.8/src/wp-includes/category-template.php#L154) and adapt to your needs. Modified to remove the `<a>` tags but not tested, compare to the original, adapt if needed, and add it to the theme's `functions.php`:

```
function category_list_so_22771587( $separator = '' ) {
    global $wp_rewrite;
    $categories = get_the_category( $post_id );
    $thelist = '';
    $i = 0;
    foreach ( $categories as $category ) {
        if ( 0 < $i )
            $thelist .= $separator;
        switch ( strtolower( $parents ) ) {
            case 'multiple':
                if ( $category->parent )
                    $thelist .= get_category_parents( $category->parent, true, $separator );
                $thelist .= $category->name;
                break;
            case 'single':
                if ( $category->parent )
                    $thelist .= get_category_parents( $category->parent, false, $separator );
                $thelist .= $category->name;
                break;
            case '':
            default:
                $thelist .= $category->name;
        }
        ++$i;
    }
    return $thelist;
}
```

And modify your template to:

```
$categories_list = category_list_so_22771587( __( ', ', 'gridster' ) );
```

Comment: hmmm, some revenge downvote... hi buddy, I remember you, cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Do you just want to hide the links? If so use css:

```
.postmeta a {display: none}
```

**Edit,** you can also "disable" those links in css:

```
.postmeta a {
  pointer-events: none;
  cursor: default;
}
```

Comment: He wanted to output only the name, not wrapped inside a <a> tag

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve categories, extract the 'name' column of each items, and implode each values with a comma:

```
 <?= implode(', ', (array_column(get_the_category(), 'name')))?>
```

Or you can retrieve categories list with link, and remove a tags :

```
 <?= strip_tags(get_the_category_list(', ')) ; ?>
```